# Difference between real and complex solution in differential equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

"Given the differential equation: $$\begin{bmatrix} x_1'(t) \\ x_2'(t) \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & -5 \\ 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t)\end{bmatrix}, t \in \mathbb{R}$$"

This matrix has complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but could someone elaborate on the main differences between the complete *complex* solution and the complete *real* solution, which I believe is a subset of the first.

And what's the consequence on conditional solutions? If we for instance need a solution satisfying $x_1(0)=0$ and $x_2(0)=3$, what kind of difference does it make if we use the complete complex or complete real?

I hope my questions make sense

Comment: Both solutions are sums of exponentials $e^{pt}$ where p is an eigenvalue of the matrix. In the complex case $e^{pt} = e^{(a+ib)t}=e^{at}(cos(bt)+isin(bt)$, by DeMovire's Theorem so that the complex part of the eigenvalue introduces an oscillation into the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the initial conditions are real, then the solution must automatically be real for all $t$.

If you have the complete complex solution, it contains two arbitrary complex constants, but if you determine these complex constants so that some given *real* initial conditions are satisfied, you will get a *real* solution. (It may not immediately *look* real, but it *is* real, and you can simplify it to get rid of any $i$).

If you have the complete real solution (which, as you say, is a subset of the complete complex solution), then it contains two arbitrary real constants, and you can determine them so that any real initial conditions are satisfied. This will (of course, because of uniquess of solutions to the initial value problem) give the same final answer as if you use the complex complete solution as described in the previous paragraph.